# Alignment issue while showing webpage in UIWebview

Tags: html, iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

While showing a webpage in the UIWebview, there are some alignment issues.

Let me show that,

Below is the screenshot of the webpage in desktop browser

[image]

Below is the screenshot for while showing that page in `UIWebview` in iPhone

[image]

You can see the red dots aligned differently from its original view.

I've tried the below code to fit the screen

```
-(void)fitthescreen
{

    if ([wbvw respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)])
    {
        UIScrollView *scroll=[wbvw scrollView];

        float zoom=wbvw.bounds.size.width/scroll.contentSize.width;
        [scroll setZoomScale:zoom animated:YES];
    }
}
```

But same result.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the same problem using iOS Safari? This is almost certainly just an CSS problem, not a UIWebView problem.

Comment: yes same issue while showing in safari of iphone, how to fix it?

Comment: Do I need to develop webpage separately for mobile devices?

Comment: Read into CSS3 media queries / responsive web design. You don't need to develop 'separately', but you do need to develop 'for'.

Comment: thanx for the info friend, we are using bootstrap css, now started responsive web design for that. :)